# regex no Analytics API

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics-api

Estou escrevendo um código no Google App Script utilizando o Google Analytics API onde faço uma solicitação utilizando um **filtro em regex**. Um exemplo semelhante é o escrito abaixo:

```
var id = xxxxxxx;
var startDate = '2019-03-01';
var endDate = '2019-03-26';
var metrics = 'ga:uniquepageviews';
var options = {
               'dimensions':'ga:pagepath',
               'filters':'ga:pagepath=~^\/maquiagem($|\?|\/($|\?|.*))'
              };
var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(id, startDate, endDate, metrics, options);
```

o ponto é que quando rodo esse código o AppScript me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Falha na chamada de API para analytics.data.ga.get com o erro Invalid
>   regular expression: '^/maquiagem($|?|/($|?|.*))'. Regular expressions
>   should follow RE2 syntax."

Fiz vários testes com a chamada incluindo e tirando partes do regex para tentar identificar onde o programa estava rejeitando a expressão e ao que tudo indica o problema está na interrogação ("?") dentro dos parênteses (quando eu tiro do parênteses não dá problema). Mas claro, eu preciso que a interrogação fique.

Também cheguei a procurar sobre o RE2 syntax, que o erro fala, mas não fui bem sucedido em entender qual o problema.

Alguém poderia me ajudar me retornando uma possível solução para utilizar um regex que seja equivalente à esse e que a API do Google aceite?

Comment: Já tentou usar a interrogação como `?` apenas ao invés de `\?` ?

Comment: Sim, já tentei e deu no mesmo erro. Mas mesmo que tivesse dado certo, eu preciso que o regex faça match com interrogação literal.

Comment: Tenta colocando duas barras invertidas em vez de uma nos escapes. Por exemplo: `ga:pagepath=~^\/maquiagem($|\\?|\\/($|\\?|.*))`

Comment: Funcionou! Pode me explicar a lógica das duas barras invertidas?

Comment: Dentro de uma string a \ geralmente é usada para sequências de escape, como o `\n` que é uma quebra de linha (é um único caractere), o `\t` para o TAB, etc. Se vc quer o próprio caractere \, tem que escrever como \\ (que é interpretado como somente um \ ). É um problema comum quando tem que colocar uma regex dentro de uma string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582461

Comment: Outro detalhe é que `$` significa "final da string". Se quiser o próprio caractere `$`, terá que colocar a barra invertida antes dele também :-)

Comment: O @hkotsubo explicou acima =]